# Typescript error with delegate after Minification

Tags: jquery, typescript, delegates

I have the following code with delegate:

```
 $.ajax(this.validateURL, {
        type: "post",
        url: this.validateURL,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            solicitacion.procedure.set("GenarateSample", true);
            if (!response.Success) {
                notification.Show(response.Message, NotificationType.Error);
                return false;
            } else {
                if (response.Message.length > 3) {
                    this.confirm(solicitacion);
                } else {
                    this.adicionarprocedureNaGrid(solicitacion, false);
                }
                return true;
           }
        },
        error: e => {
            error_handler(e);
        }
    });
```

After minification:

```
<pre> $.ajax(this.validateURL, {
    type: "post",
    url: this.validateURL,
    data: JSON.stringify(i),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: i => t.procedure.set("GenarateSample", !0),
    i.Success? (i.Message.length > 3 ? this.confirmarprocedure(t) : this.adicionarprocedureNaGrid(t, !1), !0) : (n.Show(i.Message, NotificationType.Error), !1),
    error: n => {
        error_handler(n)
    }
}) </pre>
```

Whitout delegate, minification is correct:

```
    $.ajax(this.validateURL, {
        type: "post",
        url: this.validateURL,
        data: JSON.stringify(i),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (i) {
            return t.procedure.set("GenarateSample", !0),
                i.Success? (i.Message.length > 3 ? this.confirmarprocedure(t) : this.adicionarprocedureNaGrid(t, !1), !0) : (n.Show(i.Message, NotificationType.Error), !1)
        },
        error: n => {
            error_handler(n)
        }
    })
```

Comment: you mean arrow function ? it's not supported in ES2015 . you need a transpiler for that

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the minification *after* the TypeScript compiler has done its work.

TypeScript File (.ts)

```
const a = (y: string) => {
    return y;
}

const b = function (y: string) {
    return y;
}
```

Compiles to JavaScript (.js)

```
var a = function (y) {
    return y;
};
var b = function (y) {
    return y;
};
```

So minify the compiled JavaScript, not the TypeScript source file and it will work.

Comment: I'm going to test, modifying to something similar with indicated